# Plugin for loading comments on-demand

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments, ajax

Is there a plugin which would allow visitors to load comments when they want to, rather than always showing them by default? Preferably through an AJAX call or something to prevent page reload.

I'm thinking a nice and visible link or button with `View n comments` or something along those lines. Hope I'm making sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution oriented around users without javascript:

1. Apply a wrapper `div` to your comments, leave everything else (including CSS as is)
2. On page load, use javascript to hide the wrapper and display a link or button or something for 'view comments'
3. onclick 'view comments', fade/slide the comments in.

The advantage to this is that your comments will still be visible to those not using javascript (specifically: search engines), but it will behave exactly like it would if you made the changes in the CSS.

Comment: Don't really care that much about users without javascript, but search engines is a good point. Maybe I'll go for this. How would you wrap the comments in a div? And where would you put the javascript?

Comment: You really should care about users without javascript...it's not much, but even 1% of the internet is a tremendous number of people, and you have to think about them for search engines anyways...progressive enhancement is the name of the game. `div` should go in comments.php, and you can put the .js wherever, just enqueue it correctly.